Login policy for app to create meetings via Microsoft Graph API?
I have registered an app with Microsoft Entra ID to use the Microsoft Graph API. I have granted the following delegated and app permissions (with tenant admin consent):

Calendar.Read
Calendar.ReadWrite
Group.Read.All
GroupMember.Read.All
Mail.Send
OnlineMeetings.Read.All
OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All
People.Read.All
User.Read.All
User.ReadBasic.All
User.ReadWrite.All

I am using this registered app on my local machine to authenticate a backend built in Node.js v21, using the @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client  and @azure/msal-node libraries. The created client can use other endpoints without any issues, however, when querying the endpoint
 /users/${userId}/onlineMeetings, the console responds:
Error: No application access policy found for this application.
I understand that access policies are Microsoft Entra ID policies, but I have not been able to find the necessary settings to prevent the error from occurring.

Disable all Microsoft managed policies, assuming that the problem is excessive restrictions.
Since the same error persists, I understood that the registered application needed a Policy that governs it directly, so first create an application role with the value OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All.
In the integration wizard section, I followed the necessary steps, although I did not understand the section "If API requests are expected on behalf of users, define the scopes that the API exposes."

